# TypeError: bad operand type for unary +: 'str' python

Tags: python, operands

```
number=int(input("Please enter a number:     "))

for b in range(1,11):
    b=int(b)
    output=int (number) *int (b)
    print(+str (b) +" times "+ str (number) +" is " +output)
```

I want the program to ask for a number and then print its times table up to 10*number, however I keep getting this error. BTW, I'm doing GCSE computing.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\jcowp_000\Documents\School\Lutterworth\Computing\Documents_-_-___________---________---______-_-_-_-__-__\Python\Python manual tasks.py", line 21, in <module>
print(+str (b) +" times "+ str (number) +" is " +output)
TypeError: bad operand type for unary +: 'str'
```

Comment: Why are you doing `b = int(b)`? `b` is already an `int`. Also, what are you trying to do by `+str(b)`?

Comment: I want it to print, for example, 1 times 5 is 5, 2 times 5 is 10, etc

Comment: trailing + should not be there and you should also convert your output to string. Otherwise Python will not know if you want to perform concatenation of strings or addition of numbers.

Comment: with str(b) being the 1 or the 2 in my example

Comment: how do you convert an output to string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're trying to do:

```
number = int(input("Please enter a number:     "))

for b in range(1,11):
    output = int(number) * b   # b is already an int, you can use it directly in computations
    print(str(b) + " times " + str(number) + " is " + str(output))
```

Note that `+str(b)` is incorrect syntax, and also note you cannot concatenate `" is"`, which is a `str`, with `output`, which is an `int`.

Comment: that sounded sarcastic

Comment: although this answer is correct, i would like to point out `int(b)` makes no sense as already suggested by @Donald in the comments above. You could simply do `output = int(number) * b`

Answer (score 0):

```py
number=int(input("Please enter a number:     "))

for b in range(1,11):
    b=int(b)
    output=int (number) *int (b)
    print(b, "times",number,"is",output)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).